# Is possible to load .XIB or Storyboard inside the React Native library?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have create one module for react native, it have more the five viewcontroller. so i take the XIB for each of the viewcontroller. but the XIB doesn't load inside the library.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showFirstVC){

    UIViewController *root = RCTPresentedViewController();

   FVCViewController *ViewController = (FVCViewController *)[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FVCViewController" bundle:nil];

   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ViewController];
   navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [root presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Can you help me is it possible to load XIB or Storyboard inside the library in react native.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add any resources like so, with the folder reference, and then needed filetypes:

```
s.resources = "ios/MiSnapSDK/MiSnapUX/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets}"
```